# How to show Image response to view in EXTJS 4?

Tags: web-services, extjs, extjs4, png, extjs-mvc

I have web service in my controller that returns me a image in following format. I want to know that how i load this image response in my view. I use EXTJS 4 MVC architecture.I dont know this image is in which format. Please help me for this problem.

RESPONSE:-

�PNG

���
IHDR�����������ߊ���sRGB�������gAMA�����a���    pHYs�������o�d���IDATx^��y�ř'���x1��?^�/��jv��g�Ƙ՞��iO����VV�M$�H�IhC�վ��e�lhcw���c���6;����}Y�����:����e����2++������U�1c����@�� ����@�� ����@�� ����@�� ����@�� ����@�� ����@�� ����@�� ����@�� ����@`�ظq�G)-�˖-�S���l�6��
4��fmc��t��    gj���[�э���{�����O?�^y���{�!��l�6��{`Mcmc�{��^&��
i߿OM����Q��;�}ꩧ�y��w0�
�

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ext.Img` - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Img and assign `src` property to the URL of your web service call.